# Proxying JAX-RS requests to another service

Tags: jax-rs

I have a JAX-RS service, i am trying to write a small proxy which intercepts the incoming request and forward it to another alternate service, process returned response and give to client back.

Specifically seeing as what information i need to extract from ContainerRequestFilter and copy to another request for sending to alternate service.

Any example references are appreciated!

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: All requests must be intercepted? Do you have more than one endpoint in your application?

Comment: Thats a good question Molin, i need few requests to be proxied, which i believe we can use some annotations of some sort.